# Can't find LibreOffice or OpenOffice executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Can you help me?
When I try to use libre gem, I get the below error. But I already installed Libre office on my laptop and I am using win10, does it matter?

IOError at /users/8/request
Can't find LibreOffice or OpenOffice executable.

[Can't find LibreOffice or OpenOffice executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdAy7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow (:

The short answer is that soffice.exe must be in your path.

How did I get there?

1. I did a web search for "ruby libre gem"
2. That took me to the GitHub page for libreconv: https://github.com/DocSpring/libreconv
3. I cloned that so I could search easier through the code, but there's really only one file of interest: libreconv.rb
4. In the `initialize` method, the `soffice_command` member is set by asking `which` to find 'soffice' or 'soffice.bin'; `which` is going to search through all pathed folders to find the thing it's looking for

On a *nix machine, it's very likely that soffice.bin will end up in the user's path. On Windows, less so. But you can fix that by adding the folder where that lives (probably "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program", if you've used the default install like I have) to your PATH, using system settings:

1. press Win+X
2. select "Settings" from the menu that pops up
3. in the search box type "Path"
4. select "Edit the system environment variables" or "Edit the environment variables  for your account"
5. double-click the PATH entry -- either in the system box (so it will apply to everyone) or in the user box (applies only to your account)
6. Click "New"
7. Paste in the path given above (assuming, again, default installation folder)